# How to add permission while making a request to outlook calendar api (create event)?

Tags: ajax, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, unauthorized

I was trying to add outlook calendar api (create event) to my web app but stuck on an error of unauthorization. So I guess it might be the reason that I did not add permission?
This is my ajax function:

```
function addEvent(){
    var newEvent = {};
    newEvent.subject = document.getElementById('event-name').value;
    newEvent.body = document.getElementById('event-des').value;
    newEvent.start = document.getElementById('start-time').value;
    newEvent.end = document.getElementById('end-time').value;
    newEvent.location = document.getElementById('location').value;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newEvent));

    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    res.setHeader('prefer', 'outlook.timezone="Pacific Standard Time"');
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(newEvent));
}
```

But I got an error of unauthorized to make post request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events. Can any one point out what I am missing here? I am very new to this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to authenticate and work with permissions to securely access data through Microsoft Graph. Explore the documentation below to learn about app registration, authentication libraries, authorization, and other parts of the Microsoft identity platform that support Microsoft Graph development in the  [Microsoft Graph auth overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/) section for more information.